# Is there a way Make cells right to left using openpyxl?

Tags: python, openpyxl

Is there a way Make cells right to left using openpyxl ?

I have found a way to make the whole sheet right to left `sheet.sheet_view.rightToLeft = True`, but I want the text direction inside the cells

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer, it's called reading order on the alignment style object.

so for `cell` object apply the following

```py
alignment = copy(cell.alignment)
alignment.readingOrder = 2 #RTL
cell.alignment = alignment
```